# Stateless & stateful worker scenario

Tags: celery, message-queue, distributed-computing, distributed, stateless

I have one scenario:
Say I have a worker in a distributed system whose task it to accept a task and apply business logic on that task and throw the result to some other service.
So say there can be 3 types of requests i.e; the worker is able to differentiate requests and apply corresponding business logic on those requests. So is the worker stateful or stateless in this scenario?

To my observation, the worker is stateless as the worker doesn't save any information about the task, it doesn't care what operations were applied to the task earlier, neither it cares about what will happen to it in the future. So basically there is no state sharing issues. The worker just cares about processing the task with the corresponding business logic. The business logic is say for example - formatting the data / parsing & converting the data so that the data becomes consumable in the system.

Comment: looks like the worker is statefull becasue of you are sending the result to other service.
you may check SAGA (long living transaction) pattern. each consumer may apply business role and throw it to another  consumer and you dont lose the state  of object or business.

Comment: In that scenario, every worker is state-full. When data is processed, it may get propagated through many different workers and ultimately may get dumped to a db say. So in order to propagate the data to the destination, the workers have to apply business logic which keeps preparing the data. So are not all workers state full from this point of view? Please let me know your understanding with examples if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your workers are stateless. They don't hold any information in-memory except the bare minimum required to send and receive data from other services. If the worker crashes, another worker can replace it seamlessly w/o need of syncing information from a persistent data store.